# Spring data jpa Join fetch paging

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 3 with spring data jpa. In a Specification query, I do a query to get all Person with its childs

```
Page<Person> personPage = personRepository.findAll(personSpecification.search(search), pageable);

public Specification<Person> search(Person search search) {
    return (root, cq, cb) -> {

        Join<Person, Child> childJoin;

        if (Long.class != cq.getResultType()) {
            childJoin = (Join) root.fetch("childs", JoinType.LEFT);
        } else {
            //for paging useless to do fetch
            childJoin = (Join) root.join("childs", JoinType.LEFT);
        }

        ...
    };
}
```

So I get one query and I get child

In log I see

> org.hibernate.orm.query                  : HHH90003004: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory

If I change fetch for a Join, I get n+1 issue

So it's seem ram vs multiple query issue

Comment: Maybe try with `EntityGraph` through `EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor`.